# Trying to print over line, gets me extra "![K" somewhere

Tags: bash, haskell

#### The problem

I've read that you can use `\033[K` to erase to the end of a bash line, and `\r` to go back to the beginning of the line. So you can combine them to override a line with another line.

I tried different configurations and in pretty much any arrangement, even.

```
\r\033[K\rString\r
```

there's always an extra `![K` coming from somewhere.

#### The actual Haskell script details

The actual script I'm using right now is:

```
putStrOver :: String -> IO ()
putStrOver str = putStr $ "\033[K" ++ str ++ "\r"
```

and used as:

```
forM [1..n] $ \i -> do
    -- calc percentage
    putStrOver $ "Generating: " ++ show perc ++ "%"
```

And what it gets me is this:

[image: Image showing an extra "![K" is prepended on the printed screen]

#### Trying to isolate the problem

So there's always this annoying extra `![K` part that is generated from somewhere. I first thought it could have been some `!` coming from somewhere else, so I took a bran new GHCi environment and tested just that function with:

```
mapM_ (\i -> putStrOver . show $ i) [1..]
```

and it still prints `![K`:

[image: Example of the problem with the GHCi script]

I'm using the Terminal bash on a Mac OS X Yosemite, if that counts for anything.

#### Question

What is going on? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Haskell, unlike all other programming languages I'm aware of (or at least can think of right now), doesn't interpret `\033` as an octal literal but a decimal one. This explains why you get `!`, because `!` is 33 in ASCII.

The solution is to replace `\033` with `\o33` (or `\x1b` or `\27`) in the haskell code. Or, perhaps more prettily, with `\ESC`. They all mean the same thing, so pick the one you think is most readable.